# In which table does Postgres records the savepoint name, when we define a savepoint in a transaction?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I always found a blocking query in the database is "**ROLLBACK TO _EXEC_SVP_0x16539e0**", and I suspect that the database is not able to find the savepoint name, due to which there is no end to a transaction.

So, I want to know if there is any way that I can find all the existing savepoint names that are active.

Comment: I think that your suspicion is unfounded. It just happened that the last executed statement was `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`, which by itself doesn't take any locks, nor can it be blocked.

Comment: but, if I query the blocking queries, then I am getting the ROLLBACK, additionally, the state, of this transaction is always "idle in transaction"

Comment: Right. But there is no "blocking query", there is only a *blocking transaction*. Some statement that was run *before* the `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` in the same transaction is blocking you.

Comment: Got it, thank you, let me try to find that statement, any suggestion is welcome.